# How can I "index" my Object using the key generated by my function from its Object.keys(obj) array?

Tags: javascript, object, indexing

I created a function that uses the method Object.keys(myObj) to generate a random key from its array. I want to use the value returned by the variable currentCountry to grab the corresponding value from the matching key/value pair in my object.

I tried directly substituting the variable name in to try and call the method that way (countryObj.currentCountry), but that came back 'undefined'

I've done a good bit of Google searching but so far haven't found what I need to do this.

```
let countryObj = {
    Argentina: 'buenos Aires',
    Bolivia: 'Sucre',
    Brazil: 'Brasilia',
    Chile: 'Santiago',
    Columbia: 'Bogotá',
    Ecuador: 'Quito',
    Guyana: 'Georgetown',
    Paraguay: 'Asunción',
    Peru: 'Lima',
    Suriname: 'Paramaribo',
    Uruguay: 'Montevideo',
    Venezuela: 'Caracas'
} 

let keys = Object.keys(countryObj); // returns an array of the keys (country names) in countryObj

let currentCountry = "";
let randomCountry =  function() { // returns a randomly chosen country from the keys array and writes
    // ... the country to the <p> element in index.html    
    currentCountry = keys[Math.floor(keys.length * Math.random())];
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = currentCountry;
    return currentCountry;
```

When I tried directly subbing the variable name to call the method it returned 'undefined'

Comment: You might don't call randomCountry function and also If you want to show it you should add to the p element an id or class or use getElementsByTagName

Comment: Your code works fine as is.  Show us how you called the function.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried directly substituting the variable name in to try and call the
>   method that way (countryObj.currentCountry), but that came back
>   'undefined'

Rather than `countryObj.currentCountry`, you should use `countryObj[currentCountry]`, the syntax is the same as an array, but if `countryObj` is an object, then it returns the value for the key `currentCountry` on the object.

You don't show how you call the function, but a working example could be:

```
let countryObj = {
    Argentina: 'buenos Aires',
    Bolivia: 'Sucre',
    Brazil: 'Brasilia',
    Chile: 'Santiago',
    Columbia: 'Bogotá',
    Ecuador: 'Quito',
    Guyana: 'Georgetown',
    Paraguay: 'Asunción',
    Peru: 'Lima',
    Suriname: 'Paramaribo',
    Uruguay: 'Montevideo',
    Venezuela: 'Caracas'
} 

let keys = Object.keys(countryObj); // returns an array of the keys (country names) in countryObj


let randomCountry =  function() {
    // returns a randomly chosen country from the keys array and writes
    // ... the country to the <p> element in index.html    
    let currentCountry = keys[Math.floor(keys.length * Math.random())];
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = currentCountry;
    return currentCountry;
}

let currentCountry = randomCountry();

console.log(countryObj[currentCountry]);
```

Comment: To test this I used console.log(countryObj[currentCountry]); and in the chrome browser it did not have any effect. Nothing was logged in the JS console. I do not think it is accepting the variable in place of the object method.

Comment: I edited to show a fuller example - I changed currentCountry to be local to randomCountry, but you can easily make it global again if that is needed

Comment: If you get no console output then randomCountry() is not being called. You should include more code to show the flow of execution.